# Can't connect to MySQL on ScotchBox

Tags: mysql

I'm getting connection refused every time I try to connect to MySQL server on Vagrant's ScotchBox.

I've doubled checked my username / password combinations but still no access.

I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where should I've asked it?

Comment: ServerFault perhaps. Or SuperUser. Or DBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should read the rules to get used to the site.

Regarding your problem: ScotchBox doesn't allow remote connections to MySQL server out of the box. You'll need to do the following steps:

Edit the /etc/mysql/my.cnf and comment the line 47 from:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Update MySQL user table doing:

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET host='%' WHERE user='root' AND host='127.0.0.1';
```

Restart MySQL service.

You should now be able to connect to MySQL server.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your solution

Comment: Allowing root access from arbitrary hosts is an utterly terrible idea. Don't do this.